# Reloading DIV that contains just a script, and executing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot figure out how to reload the content within this div periodically:

```
    <div id="redditFeed">
         <script src="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/hot/.embed?limit=10&t=all&style=off" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

I've tried some jquery, but the closest I've come is reloading the script into the div without executing it. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you please share some relevant code that you have tried so far.

Comment: how are you reloading the div? share that code as well

Comment: please provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Ok, I'll point to the elephant in the room and ask, "Why is there a `<script>` element inside a `<div>?" Is there some kind of hack or new way of doing things I'm not aware of? It's probably valid yet I don't see any advantage in doing so.

Comment: @zer00ne A `script` tag is typically placed in the head or just before the closing `body` tag, but you *could* place it anywhere after any dom elements the script targets. While I personally wouldnt drop them about in my HTML....one could

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) to load script again.

```
setTimeout(function() {
$.getScript( "http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/hot/.embed?limit=10&t=all&style=off", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I'm getting this console warning:

"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."